# Button onclick there is a form and an ajax to call both simultaneously?

Tags: php, jquery, html

```
<form method="post" action="test.php">
    <select id="select" name="name">
                    <option class="km" id="52" value="14">h</option>
                    <option id="1" value="2">a</option>
                    <option id="1.5" value="29">b</option>
                    <option id="2" value="29">c</option>
                    <option id="3" value="3">d</option>
                    <option id="4" value="41">e</option>
                    <option id="5" value="49">f</option>
        <option id="0" value="5">g</option>
    </select>
<input type="submit" id="addsubmit" class="btn success"></span>
</form>
```

With the submit button I want to call an ajax at the same time.

Case1-Ajax is working fine without form action.

Case 2-When both are included only form is working not the ajax.

```
$("#addsubmit").click(function()
```

{ 
call an ajax
}

Comment: You can make a button (`input type="button"`), `onclick` of it run AJAX and then submit the form `jQuery('form').submit()`

Comment: Sorry i am new to jquery please can u be more specific..Thanks in advance

Comment: check my @user2727841 answer if you've any query ask me!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its up you and your requirement call both simultaneously or individuals

for both this code will help you

```
<form method="post" action="process.php" id="testForm">
    <select id="select" name="name">
        <option class="km" id="52" value="14">h</option>
        <option id="1" value="2">a</option>
        <option id="1.5" value="29">b</option>
        <option id="2" value="29">c</option>
        <option id="3" value="3">d</option>
        <option id="4" value="41">e</option>
        <option id="5" value="49">f</option>
        <option id="0" value="5">g</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" id="addsubmit" class="btn success" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and ajax code is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#addsubmit").click(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "process.php",
         data: "select=" + $("#select").val(),
         cache: false,
         success: function(data) {
            $("#testForm").submit();
            alert(data);
            console.log(data);
         }
      });
      return false;
    });
});
```

If you want to submit with javascript change `type="submit"` to `type="button"` and javascript code will be the same

```
<input type="button" id="addsubmit" class="btn success" value="Submit">
```

now javascript will submit your form.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#addsubmit').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    /* your ajax call */
});
```

Or

```
<form method="post" action="test.html" id="form_test">
<input type="text"  name="field_tb"/>
<input type="submit" id="bt" />
</form>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#bt').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post('test.php',function(){
            alert('work');
            $('#form_test').submit();
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: now the ajax is calling and the form is not working.@The Fire TITAN

Comment: In your ajax function success try to add these code at end:
$('#addsubmit').submit();

Comment: this is my form test i used and it's worked great:

<form method="post" action="test.html" id="form_test">
<input type="text"  name="field_tb"/>
<input type="submit" id="bt" />
</form>
<script>
$(function(){
 $('#bt').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
  $.post('test.php',function(){
   alert('work');
   $('#form_test').submit();
  });
    });
});
</script>

Comment: need min 15 reputation..Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is first do the AJAX call with the data, then submit the form normally.

First, you should change the type of the button from `submit` to `button`:

```
<input type="button" id="addsubmit" class="btn success">
```

Then you need to use jquery to complete the javascript with ease:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $('#addsubmit').click(function(){
         var post_data = $(this).closest('form').serialize();
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "example.php",
             data: post_data,
             success: function(response_data){
                 //you need to listen for the response of the server, and decide if you want to continue.
                 $(this).closest('form').submit()
             },
             error: function(){
                 alert('there was an error, write your error handling code here.');
             }
         });
     });
</script>
```

Comment: instead of  `$('form')` better would be to target specific FORM: `$(this).closest('form')` and do the same in success callback with setting a closure variable or option context of ajax request to `this`

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind actually i want to do the form action to test.php and by ajax i want to call a example.php.can u help

Comment: @KoushikMallik, To do what you suggested, you just need to change the target script in the AJAX call.  See in the answer, I added in your `example.php`.